# Mac bash run commands in parallel, where one process does not exit

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to find a way to run two processes in parallel from one command in the Mac terminal, where one command does not exit. Essentially, I want to run the following command to auto-watch karma tests:

`npm karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch`

I also want to open the browser to the karma debug runner page:

`http://localhost:9876/debug.html`

I want to open the browser about 15 seconds after starting the `karma start` command above. I can't figure out how to do this in parallel in a one-liner.

Here's what I've come up with so far, after about two hours of searching around:

`npx karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch & ( sleep 15 && open http://localhost:9876/debug.html )`

This works the way I want except for the fact that karma seems to run in a separate context - which means the user can't `Ctrl+C` and kill the node process, they'd have to do it manually.

Comment: Just guessing as I don't use those commands, but maybe try a compound command rather than a subshell `npm ... & { sleep 15 && open ... ; }`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That returns `sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file` not sure why though?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nevermind, I missed the semicolon at the end there. That seems to have the same problem - works but can't Ctrl+C on the karma process.

Comment: What about in the reverse order with the browser in the background and the `npm` thing in the foreground? Something like `( sleep 15 && open ... ) & npm ...`

Comment: Looks like that worked! I swear I tried that earlier but maybe I had a syntax error. Thanks!

Comment: I also just found out that I can pass argument to karma to open the browser anyways `npx karma start --browser Chrome`. I think I'll go with this and let karma handle it when it's ready, rather than relying on an arbitrary timer.

Comment: I think the issue is that Ctrl-C will only affect foreground processes.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the npm command in background and do a cleanup when the user presses Ctrl+C:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Initialize variables
wait_sec=15
browser_url="http://localhost:9876/debug.html"
npm_pid=""

function start_npm_command() {

  npm karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch &
  npm_pid=$!

}

function open_browser() {

  echo "Opening browser after waiting for ${wait_sec} seconds"
  sleep "${wait_sec}"
  open "${browser_url}"
  echo -e "\n\n Press 'Ctrl+C' to exit"

}

function handle_exit() {

  echo "Execute cleanup.."
  if [[ -n "${npm_pid}" ]]; then
    echo "Killing npm pid"
    kill -s SIGKILL "${npm_pid}"
  else
    echo "Do nothing"
  fi

}

function main() {

  start_npm_command
  open_browser

}

trap handle_exit SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGABRT SIGTERM
main
```

Comment: In this case, I found a couple solutions (see comments above), and decided to add the `--browser Chrome` argument flag to let karma handle it instead. However, if we decide that we need to do something more robust, I'll consider using a script like this. Thanks!